# Spot the difference

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

This [reopen review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1993189) popped up in the queue (and was unanimously left closed).
*Update: The review link now points to a different edit (the latest one).*

> [image: Not very different...]

It states that a revision was made after it was closed, but... it wasn't revised much!

In fact, looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16166903/revisions) it seems to show 4 characters have been added at the end.

> [image: Still not very different]

Perhaps there should be a higher threshold on what an edit counts towards to reopen queue?
*Adding whitespace seems like it shoudn't really count!*

*It could be that the edit was reverted within the grace period, but, if so, shouldn't the reopen queue be basing its calculation (and decision to put in the queue) **after** the grace period...*

Comment: Interestingly I can't (on latest chrome) click inline or side-by-side markdown links now for that review.

Comment: Little weird how there were characters added in, but no fixes to the obvious errors, which would have been an easy fix.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett me too come to think of it, that's how I ended up at the revision page (!)

Comment: @hayden: Raised a new bug/question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177905/cant-switch-between-different-edit-displays-in-reopen-review-queue

Comment: @CBredlow: Given that users are *very* creative when it comes to pumping their question or circumventing "problems" (does not meer our quality standards), I am not surprised *at all*.

Comment: That edit was so minor, it was below pixel level.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: Yes.  I've seen so many users try to work around the reasons they can't post instead of just *fixing* their post!

Comment: I think edits reverted in the grace period now show a revision that states something like "edit removed inside the grace period" actually