# Can't switch between different edit displays in reopen review queue

Tags: bug, review, reopen-closed

When viewing [past re-open reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history) with an edit e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1993876) I can't switch between the 3 different ways of viewing edits (inline, side-by-side, side-by-side markdown). I haven't tested active re-open reviews.

I'm using the latest public version of google chrome.

Comment: Reproducible on Firefox 20.0.1

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome 27.0.1453.65.  Clicking "inline" or "side-by-side" just adds a `#` to the URL and makes the favicon flash for a sec, like it's trying to load something, but it just stops.

Comment: Can anyone confirm whether this is only when viewing past reviews, or when viewing active/live ones too?

Comment: This seems fixed now, at least it was after I found an active re-open review item. I then tried viewing past items and that worked too.

Comment: Hmmm, scratch that, I've now tried again following my link in this question and I get the same problem.

Comment: The AJAX urls lead to 404 pages for these.

Comment: Sample review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2694845, the AJAX calls for `http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18159357/isions/diff?difftype=SideBySideHtml&_=1376149716202` and `http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18159357/isions/diff?difftype=InlineHtml&_=1376149716202` are 404 responses. Even when removing the `ivisions/` truncated part of the path the links are 404s still.

Comment: The *correct* links are `http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18159357/a5a70b77-a020-4104-8434-886ed272a153/diff?difftype=SideBySideMarkdown&_=1376149716202` and `http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18159357/a5a70b77-a020-4104-8434-886ed272a153/diff?difftype=InlineHTML&_=1376149716202`

Comment: Happens for me on active reopen reviews (on SO, DBA.SE and U&L). Fun: Clicking on the different diff modes increases the number of loading progress animations. You can get as many as you want :-)